# Python: absolute path issue

Tags: python, subprocess, absolute-path

I have several files stored in a folder called controlFiles. The path to this folder is Users/Desktop/myproject/controlFiles.

I am attempting to run a subprocess command in my python script with the following code:

```
def codeml(codeml_location, control_location):
    runPath = codeml_location + '/codeml'
    for file in os.listdir(control_location):
        ctlPath = os.path.abspath(file)
        subprocess.call([runPath, ctlPath])
```

The script's function is to run a command line tool called codeml, with the first argument being the location of the codeml executable, and the second being a folder of control files that codeml uses. When I run this script codeml runs but I get the error:

```
error when opening file /Users/Desktop/myproject/subtree.39.tre.ctl
tell me the full path-name of the file?
```

My confusion comes from the fact that the controlFiles folder is not within that path, yet it still identifies the files within the folder.

To check I was entering the correct control_location argument I edited the code as such:

```
def codeml(codeml_location, control_location):
    runPath = codeml_location + '/codeml'
    for file in os.listdir(control_location):
        print os.path.abspath(file)
```

Running this printed all the files in the controlFiles folder, but again without the folder within the paths. Here is a sample of the print out:

```
/Users/Desktop/myproject/subtree.68.tre.ctl
/Users/Desktop/myproject/subtree.69.tre.ctl
/Users/Desktop/myproject/subtree.70.tre.ctl
/Users/Desktop/myproject/subtree.71.tre.ctl
```

To run the function my control location argument is:

```
control_location = /Users/Desktop/myproject/controlFiles
```

A final point is that my working directory in the terminal is /Users/Desktop/myproject and this is because this is the location of my Click project. Why are the files being picked up but not the folder containing them?

Answer (score 3):

`os.listdir` does list the filenames in the directory `control_location` not in the current working path. So you have to join the filename with the path `control_location`:

```
for file in os.listdir(control_location):
    ctlPath = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(control_location, file))
```

Comment: Hi Daniel. This works for listing all the filenames when using print ctlPath, yet bizarrely I am still getting the same issue when using ctlPath within my subprocess command. I also tried putting os.path.abspath(os.path.join(control_location, file)) directly into the subprocess command rather than creating a variable, but still the same issue.

Comment: As above, the subprocess command is: subprocess.call([runPath, ctlPath])

Answer (score 1):

Set the cwd in the subprocess:

```
 for file in os.listdir(control_location):
    subprocess.call([runPath, file],  cwd=control_location)
```

*listdir* is just returning the basename, not the full path. Setting the cwd to where the files are will allow you to just pass file. If *listdir* can file *control_location* then subprocess should also have no issues.

Comment: Hi Padraic. Using subprocess.call([runPath, ctlPath],  cwd=control_location) still gives me the same error. That is when defining ctlPath as: os.path.abspath(os.path.join(control_location, file) as suggested by Daniel.

Comment: @spiral01,  try the edit, it should be file not ctlPath, just forget about ctlPath completely

Answer (score 0):

I managed to resolve this using:

```
for file in os.listdir(control_location):
        filepath = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(file)) 
        subprocess.call([runPath, filepath])
```

Comment: `filepath` is nothing the same as  `os.getcwd()`. And so the for-loop is useless.

Answer (score 0):

> The script's function is to run a command line tool called codeml, with the first argument being the location of the codeml executable, and the second being a folder of control files that codeml uses.

if `control_location` is the folder of control files that `codeml` uses:

```
import os
import subprocess

def codeml(codeml_location, control_location):
    executable = os.path.join(codeml_location, 'codeml')
    subprocess.check_call([executable, control_location])
```

You don't need to call `os.listdir()` here.